# Tags do JSF2 não funciona dentro de uma tag do Bootstrap

Tags: css, jsf-2.2, bootstrap-3

Criei um projeto Java Web que está usando JSF2 + Bootstrap, tanto o arquivo CSS quanto o Bootstrap estão corretamente configurados no meu projeto, e em projeto anteriores Web Java sempre era responsável pela parte de Back-End, somente agora estou começando a aprender a parte de Frond-End, e estou tendo uma dificuldade que tem me acompanhado já faz 3 semanas.

Toda tag de JSF que fica fora das tags do Bootstrap funciona normalmente utilizando o link do arquivo CSS, porém quando eu coloco uma tag do JSF dentro de uma tag do Bootstrap ele passa a não funcionar, as tags de JSF somente funcionam quando eu aplico as configuração do CSS direto na pagina XHTML, e isso não é uma boa prática de desenvolvimento Frond-End como vê abaixo;

**Modelo que está funcionando:**

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="carolina.jpg" style="margin-left: 50px;"/>
```

O que eu preciso é saber porque isso acontece,  as configurações deveriam ser essas abaixo, sendo que elas não funcionam.  será que estou criando os códigos de forma errada na pagina?

**Isso é na pagina:**

```
<h:graphicImage library="images" name="carolina.jpg" styleClass="foto_carolina"/>
```

**Isso está no arquivo CSS:**

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";



.foto_carolina{
        margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Eu até tentei desta forma, sendo que também não funcionou:

Essá é minha pagina completa:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.css" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="sistema.css" />


    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bootstrap.js" />



</h:head>


<style>

body {
    width:80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

</style>

<h:body>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="logotipoK.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a><span class="divider"></span></li>
                        <li><a href="#">O PLano</a> <span class="divider"></span></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Loja Virtual</a> <span class="divider"></span></li>
                        <li class="active">Contato</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="legumes.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="plano_carolina.png"
                    style="margin-left: 50px;" />
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="carolina.jpg" styleClass="foto_carolina/>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                <div class="col-md-6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Aceito sugestões.

Se por acaso ficar a postagem não ficou muito clara, por favor me façam pergunta para eu poder esclarecer as duvidas pra que assim vocês possam me ajuda.

Estou a toda disposição, e aguardando ansiosamente ajuda.

Comment: A tag de imagem não exibe a imagem ou o estilo não é aplicado?
Se apresentar alguma mensagem de erro no console ou na tela printa ela.

Comment: respondendo sua pergunta, não é aplicado, e outra, não apresenta mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade o problema é que preciso estudar mais como funcionar a estrutura do BooTstrap, eu vou colocar a resposta, mas quem me deu o resultado da resposta foi um companheiro da comunidade do FaceBook do AlgaWorks chamado Maike Meneguetti.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">                     
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="plano_carolina.png" styleClass="img-responsive"/>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="carolina.jpg" styleClass="foto-carolina img-responsive img-rounded"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

É o arquivo CSS ficou assim;

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

body {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.foto-carolina{
        max-width: 60%;
}
```

Coloquei a resposta porque acredito que tenham outras pessoas com duvidas, e gostaria que o pessoal da comunidade do fórum não fiquem chateados comigo pelo fato de ter colocado o mérito para a comunidade do AlgaWorks do FaceBook, porque além do mais passou 4 dias e ninguém teve a disponibilidade de pelo manos tentar me ajudar.

Comment: Por favor, marque a sua resposta com *certa* se isso realmente resolve o problema.

Comment: você deveria saber que eu mesmo não posso marcar minha resposta como certa, o sistema do fórum não permite.

Comment: Pelo contrário. Tente clicar ao lado da sua pergunta, abaixo dos votos. Mova o mouse e deve aparecer um check verde. Caso não consiga, peça ajuda no chat ou aqui mesmo. Eu mesmo já fiz isso.

Answer (score -1):

esta faltando umas " para fechar

```
    styleClass="foto_carolina"/>
```

Comment: O problema não é esse.